# How do I send xml file using curl through http POST request

Tags: curl, http-post

I have a xml file in my local directory. I need to send this file to the destination url via http POST using curl. I've used following command but this gives me error -

> ERROR 2 Data at the root level is
>   invalid. Line 1, position 1.ERROR3
>   Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.%

`curl -X POST https://secure.rowebooks.co.uk/testorders/orders.aspx -F file=/Users/sts-108training/Dev/fmn/public/shared/CPI_sample.xml`

I'm I missing something?